# Can't convert ACF datepicker value to DateTime oject - gives me a boolean

Tags: date, date-time

I keep getting this error `Call to a member function modify() on boolean` with this code

```php
$date_value = the_sub_field( 'date_string' );
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_value);
$date->modify('+1 day');
```

The last line gives me an error. Both of my formats (display and return inside of ACF) are the same `'d/m/Y'`

Really frustrating stuff!

Answer (score 0):

the_sub_field() echoes out the sub field. Use get_sub_field() instead.